# Need help with Code Igniter [did not found page created]

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

so I hope someone would help me.

My first page is `leave_app.php`. In this page I put a link to apply leave, using the normal code:
`<a href="add.php">New Leave Application</a>`

However the link didn't display as I had wished for.

> "The requested URL /ci/add.php was not found on this server." and the link in the browser leads to this "http://localhost/ci/add.php".

I don't know why the server didn't find the page. I already made add.php page, also add at the leave_app controller the function `add()`.

In the `config.php` file I put `$config['index_page'] = '';`

I have asked around but no one can help. I have already surfed around, but still don't know how to solve.

Comment: where is your controller and view page. can u show the code.

Comment: why it display? undefine property add::$input                                                        if($this->input->post('save'))                                        { $this->leave_model->entry_insert(); }                                  $data = $this->leave_model->general();                            $this->load->view('add',$data); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty of Codeigniter is to rewrite urls in a clean manner, so all things go through index.php and the corresponding controller is loaded

Try accessing it like so:

```
/ci/index.php/add
```

Make sure your controller is in `application\controllers\add.php` and named `Class Add`

Comment: where, in my controller:- <?php
         class add extends CI_Controller{     
 
  function add()
  {
   $this->load->view('add'); 
   $this->load->helper('url');
   $this->load->helper('form');
   $this->load->helper('html');
   $this->load->model('leave_model'); 
   
   
   if($this->input->post('save'))
   {
    $this->leave_model->entry_insert();
   }
   
   $data = $this->leave_model->general();
   $this->load->view('add',$data);
  }

 }
?>

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking. If you need more help about codeigniter and the way it works, try the forums or search for an answer here on SO or alternatively ask another question.